# jQuery mobile handler not evaluating dynamic data

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to understand how I can dynamically pass DOM data to an event handler. So, if i have the following:

```
$('section[data-role="page"]').live("pageshow", function(event, ui){
    console.log("pageshow");  
    console.log("$('#audio-language').html());
});
```

And a `div` that gets dynamically changed by jQuery mobile like this:

```
<section data-role="page">
  <div id="audio-language">{{language}}</div>
</section>
```

My expectation were that $('#audio-language').html() would see the changes in the page but as it turns out it only sees the value in the div at the time the first jquery mobile page is loaded.

Comment: ok, all i had to do was understand selectors properly and use function context...

Comment: console.log($('#audio-language', $(this).html()).html()); works fine. please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.